# How to develop a game on a 2015 MacBook Pro without learning Metal?

Tags: c++, sfml, macos

I'm on Mac and OpenGL and Vulcan are not supported. Even worse, I'm on a 2015 MBP 13". Yeah, can't do much with that.

I spent a full year learning C++ and I have no patience to try and learn Metal which they force on Mac users (with its limited scope — Mac& iOS games only).

I wanted to learn something very useful, practical and cross platform.
I've been following the SFML Game Dev book tutorial, but the errors are many. And yes, I went to their GitHub and got the updated code. I still get errors.

SFML does a lot of handholding and I feel like I would find difficulties trying to use something complex.I really want to understand the ins and outs of talking to the system directly. Following a set library feels like I'm just memorizing steps and not understanding what's happening. It would be ok if I didn't get errors trying to do things the "easy way"

Is there a way I can work around this? I want to develop a game using my c++ knowledge.

Comment: Related: unrealengine.com

Comment: @Evorlor lol. I can't even run Unity

Comment: You should ask on https://stackoverflow.com/ about the errors you get.

Comment: *"OpenGL and Vulcan are not supported"* I thought they have OpenGL 4.1?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be able to use Vulkan there's [MoltenVK](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK), which is a wrapper on top of Metal.